# Enum in swagger-ui

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

The model schema is not appearing for the response.
The json is

```
 "200":{  
      "description":"OK",
      "schema":{  
         "type":"string",
         "enum":[  
            "SUCCESS",
            "FAILED"
         ]
      }
}
```

but nothing appears in the swagger-ui for this api

Comment: Please file an issue in the [swagger-ui](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues) project if this is happening on the current master there.

Comment: @fehguy im using springfox version 2.4.0 will attempt to use swagger-ui latest release will report back